What's wrong with the TBN map?
I'm trying to import 3D models into OpenGL using Rust and GLFT models, the problem is that this function used to work... Now it doesn't work at all!
It's working to load the 3D model, with the texture in the correct place, apparently with the normals and tangents also correct... But when I apply the TBN matrix to the normals to apply the normal map... The render comes out like this:

I don't know how to explain it, but for some reason the right part of the model (positive X is correct), but the left part (with negative X) for some reason the normal.x and tangent.x values ​​are inverted! Which causes half of the model to have visible lines of the transitions where the normal map would be...

As a result, I spent about 3 days rewriting the code looking for the error in every way... The problem is that even if I invert the normal.x and tangent.x values ​​only for the negative side of X... This creates a new problem, because I can't figure out where exactly the division between one side and the other is, which creates some strange things like...

I thought the problem was in the 3D model, but in every 3D program I opened it, it was normal and the normal map worked! So, what's wrong with my code?
fn CarregarGltf(tudo : &mut Vec<f32>, indice : &mut std::collections::HashMap<String, (i32, i32)>, modelo : &str){
    let local_exe = std::env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let local = local_exe.display();
    let original_tamanho = tudo.len()/22;
    let (gltf, buffers, _) = gltf::import(format!("extras/{}.gltf",modelo)).unwrap();
    //println!("Desmontando... \"{}\":",modelo);
    for m in gltf.meshes(){
        for p in m.primitives(){
            let r = p.reader(|buffer| Some(&buffers[buffer.index()]));
            let mut indices = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadIndices::U16(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_indices(){
                for v in iter{
                    indices.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut posicao = Vec::new();
            if let Some(iter) = r.read_positions(){
                for v in iter{
                    posicao.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut textura = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadTexCoords::F32(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_tex_coords(0){
                for v in iter{
                    textura.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut normais = Vec::new();
            if let Some(iter) = r.read_normals(){
                for v in iter{
                    normais.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut tangentes = Vec::new();
            if let Some(iter) = r.read_tangents(){
                for v in iter{
                    tangentes.push(v);
                }
            }
            let mut ossosid = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadJoints::U8(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_joints(0){
                for v in iter{
                    ossosid.push(v);
                }
            }
            if ossosid.len() == 0{
                println!("Cenário");
            }else{
                println!("Personagem");
            }
            let mut pesos = Vec::new();
            if let Some(gltf::mesh::util::ReadWeights::F32(gltf::accessor::Iter::Standard(iter))) = r.read_weights(0){
                for v in iter{
                    pesos.push(v);
                }
            }
            //println!("Indices : {}, {}", &indices.len()/3, &indices.len());
            for q in &indices{
                // posição
                tudo.push(posicao[*q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(posicao[*q as usize][1] as f32);
                tudo.push(posicao[*q as usize][2] as f32);
                // textura
                tudo.push(textura[*q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(textura[*q as usize][1] as f32);
                // Normais
                tudo.push(normais[*q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(normais[*q as usize][1] as f32);
                tudo.push(normais[*q as usize][2] as f32);
                // Tangentes
                tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][0] as f32);
                tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][1] as f32);
                tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][2] as f32);
                // ossosid e pesos
                if ossosid.len() != 0{
                    tudo.push(ossosid[*q as usize][0] as f32);
                    tudo.push(ossosid[*q as usize][1] as f32);
                    tudo.push(ossosid[*q as usize][2] as f32);
                    tudo.push(ossosid[*q as usize][3] as f32);
                    // pesos
                    let tmp = pesos[*q as usize][0] + pesos[*q as usize][1] + pesos[*q as usize][2] + pesos[*q as usize][3];
                    tudo.push(pesos[*q as usize][0]/tmp);
                    tudo.push(pesos[*q as usize][1]/tmp);
                    tudo.push(pesos[*q as usize][2]/tmp);
                    tudo.push(pesos[*q as usize][3]/tmp);
                }else{
                    tudo.push(0.0);tudo.push(0.0);tudo.push(0.0);tudo.push(0.0);
                    tudo.push(0.0);tudo.push(0.0);tudo.push(0.0);tudo.push(0.0);
                }
                // aoffset
                let rx = ((rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..200000) as f32)/100.0)-1000.0;
                let rz = ((rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..200000) as f32)/100.0)-1000.0;
                tudo.push(rx);
                tudo.push(0.0);
                tudo.push(rz);
            }
        }
    }
    indice.insert(modelo.to_string(),(original_tamanho as i32,(tudo.len()/22-original_tamanho) as i32));
    println!("Tudo do \"{}\" : {}, {}", modelo.to_string(), original_tamanho, tudo.len()/22-original_tamanho);
}

update 1
I discovered that the error is somehow in the bitangent, I don't know how to explain it but when I use:
B = cross(NOR,T);

The error appears on the right side of the model.
When I do the opposite:
B = cross(T,NOR);

The right side appears correctly and the left side appears incorrect.
How do I fix this? I tried to modify the X position, but it just messed up the whole scene and although it seemed to fix the left and right sides it created an error in the middle of the model!

I used this snippet in the code:
TBN = mat3(T,cross(NOR,T)*(-outpos1.x/abs(outpos1.x)),NOR);


I don't have time to write a proper answer at the moment, but this search may lead you in useful directions. We'll usually use the w component of the mesh's tangent vector to store information about whether the UVs are mirrored and need to be flipped when creating the TBN matrix.

You hit the nail on the head, this is the first time I've used tangent in code in a more practical way and I thought I only needed XYZ for it to work, but after I added W and multiplied the bitangent, the error disappeared!

Excellent! Want to post an answer below, showing how you modified your code / model and the fixed results?

In short, the error was that I didn't understand that the tangent should come with XYZW and I used only XYZ... In short, I added in the function that loaded the model:
tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][0] as f32);
tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][1] as f32);
tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][2] as f32);
tudo.push(tangentes[*q as usize][3] as f32); // this

And then in the shader I just multiplied the bitangent by the tangent.w:
TBN = mat3(T,tangent.w*cross(NOR,T),NOR);

This fixed the model.
